# GDPR SDK Error [ Android studio ]

Tags: java, android, admob, main-activity

I want to install GDPR SDK in my Android Studio project, but I have an error message in MainActivity when I call requestConsentInfoUpdate() on an instance of ConsentInformation.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////// CONSENT GDPR

        ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(context);
        String[] publisherIds = {"pub-6026672754365474"};
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
                // User's consent status successfully updated.
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(String errorDescription) {
                // User's consent status failed to update.
            }
        });
```

I have error on `getInstance(context);`:

```
Error : cannot resolve symbol context
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `context`. replace that with `getApplicationContext()` or `this` :

```
ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(this);
// or    
ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Thanks
when I make getApplicationContext() or this
I tested my app on android devise, it displays a message " unfortunately app has stopped "

Comment: you have another problems for that error. It's an answer for current question @Ahmed

Comment: Accept answer if it was helpful, to help another guys too @Ahmed